# How to improve php-fpm for wordpress with the help of modules?

Tags: php-fpm, wordpress, php7

```
~]# php -m
    [PHP Modules]
    bz2
    calendar
    Core
    ctype
    curl
    date
    dom
    exif
    fileinfo
    filter
    ftp
    gd
    gettext
    hash
    iconv
    json
    libxml
    mbstring
    memcache
    mysqli
    mysqlnd
    openssl
    pcntl
    pcre
    PDO
    pdo_mysql
    pdo_sqlite
    Phar
    readline
    Reflection
    session
    SimpleXML
    sockets
    sodium
    SPL
    sqlite3
    standard
    tokenizer
    xml
    xmlreader
    xmlwriter
    xsl
    Zend OPcache
    zip
    zlib
```

What extra modules I could need to help speed up the site ?
php version is 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the more modules you load into PHP, the more resources it will take up.

So my advise would be to look at your codes, and determine what is the functions that you actually use, then only load those modules.

for example, you actually have "mysqli", "mysqlnd", "pdo_mysql" loaded, and they are all used to connect and query from the MySQL database. You should determine which one is the one used, and unload the others.

Same with the "pdo_mysql" and "pdo_sqlite" module. Are you using SQLite? If not, you should unload the SQLite modules.

I Also see a lot of XML parsing libraries, if not needed, those could be unloaded.